# If Ramanujan's tau function has a prime power zero then $\ldots$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime number.
Ramanujan's tau function satisfies:

(a)
$$
\tau(p^{n+1}) = \tau(p^n)\tau(p)-p^{11}\tau(p^{n-1})
$$
for all positive integers $n>0.$
So $\tau(p)=0$ implies

(b)
$$
\tau(p^{2r+1})=0,
$$
and
(c)
$$
\tau(p^{2r})=(-1)^rp^{11r}
$$
for all nonnegative integers $r \geq 0.$

Assume now that (b) happens for {\it{some}} $r \geq 0.$

Question: Can we get $\tau(p)=0$ ?

We may assume from classic Lehmer's result that $n=p^{2r+1}$ is {\it{not}} the smallest $n$ with $\tau(n)=0.$

Seems that adding condition (c) for the same $r$ works, since (essentially): if $p^k || \tau(p)$
then $k$ should be very small.

Comment: @Luis, I vote down since I see no mathematical content. The famous conjecture $\tau(p)\ne0$ is plausible enough (maybe, even more than RH, at least to me). I vote to close as this is not a research level.

Comment: @Wadim: Thanks for vote. Too easy the special case when we add
condition (c) ???

Comment: The question is \it{NOT} about discovering a possible zero of $\tau$
(out of reach of course)
It is modestly to see if some necessary conditions may be sufficient
or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Theorem 2 of Lehmer's paper "The vanishing of Ramanujan's function $\tau(n)$" says that the smallest $n$ for which $\tau(n)=0$ is prime.

More generally, this paper should be of interest to you given your question.

Comment: @Laurent: I know the paper. Using it I putted in the question that we may assume that
the power of $p$ (assumed to be a possible zero of $\tau$) is not the smallest one.
Indeed, Lehmer proved these result  by playing with the known congruences for $\tau$ together with
some computations. (He succedded since being the smallest possible
zero implies reasonable computations).

Comment: @Luis: if I'm not mistaken, the proof of theorem 2 consists in showing that if $\tau(p^n)=0$ then $\tau(p)=0$ which does answer your question.

Comment: @Laurent: Sure, but assuming that $N=p^n$ is the "smallest" $N$
such that $\tau(N)=0.$
If we do not assume this the proof of Lehmer vanishes !


Comment: @Luis: Where in the proof of "if $\tau(p^n)=0$ then $\tau(p)=0$" (bottom of page 430 and top of page 431) is it assumed?

Comment: @Laurent: You are right !  Lehmer's result uses formula (5), in page 667, line -3.
 I wondered (a little quickly)
to get the result only from formulas (3) and (4), as in my question here...


Comment: Assuming only (c)  (instead of (b)) I do not know what happens.

Comment: @Luis, condition (c) also implies $\tau(p)=0$ : let $1-\tau(p)X+p^{11} X^2 = (1-\alpha X)(1-\beta X)$ with $|\alpha|=|\beta| = p^{11/2}$ (by Deligne). Condition (c) says that $\sum_{i=0}^{2r} \alpha^i \beta^{2r-i} = (-1)^r p^{11r}$ which implies that $\alpha/\beta$ is a root of unity, so some $\tau(p^k)$ is zero.

Comment: @Fancois: This is very nice !

Comment: @Luis, $\tau$ is a multiplicative function, hence if $\tau(N)=0$ then $\tau(p^n)=0$ for some prime power $p^n$ exactly dividing $N$. This is simply because nonzero complex numbers have a nonzero product.

Comment: @GH: Right, but $\tau(p_1^n)=0$ does not (generally) implies
$\tau(p^h)=0$ for $p^h < p_1^n.$

Comment: @Luis: Yes, but you seemed not to understand that the smallest $N$ such that $\tau(N)=0$ is trivially a prime power, which follows from the multiplicativity of $\tau$ (as I explained). Earlier you stated this as a nontrivial assumption, read back your second comment in this thread. 

Comment: @GH:The important things about this post appears in Laurent's answer and in Francois's comment.

Comment: @Luis: Sure. I just said something easy (that you did not understand before) hoping that you would be grateful.

Comment: @GH: I think you misunderstood - Luis was concerned that the proof would only work for N being the smallest prime power with $\tau(N) = 0$, as opposed to larger prime powers for which $\tau(N) = 0$.

Comment: @ndkrempel: Thanks for the clarification, I misunderstood indeed.

@Luis: I apologize for misunderstanding you!